# How to open multiple csv. files with 3 columns each (Gene, length and counts) in a single R df?

Tags: r, dataframe, rna-seq

I am new to R and I was trying to open multiple files with read_csv. I have tried the following methods but they always return empty columns for most samples except the first one (the raw data looks okay).

```
# Importing multiple csv files at once - returns empty columns for most samples
setwd("~/Desktop/cardio_metabolism_annotated_counts/asdf RNA seq/raw_data")
install.packages('data.table')
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df <- 
  list.files(path = "/Users/asdf/Desktop/cardio_metabolism_annotated_counts/asdf RNA seq/raw_data/", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~fread(.))

head(df)

# Using tidyverse - second method
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  list.files(path = "~/Desktop/nox4_cardio_metabolism_annotated_counts/Nox4 RNA seq/raw_data/", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~read_csv(.))
df
```

This is an example of what I get after running the first one:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/9w(...)aded_packages
> library(tidyverse)
> library(dplyr)
> library(data.table)
> df <- 
+   list.files(path = "/Users/asfd/Desktop/_cardio_metabolism_annotated_counts/ RNA seq/raw_data/", pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
+   map_df(~fread(.))
> 
> head(df)
          GeneID Length R210808_2459_Tg_counts R210809_2459_Tg_counts R210810_2460_Tg_counts
1: 4933401J01Rik   1070                      0                     NA                     NA
2:       Gm26206    110                      0                     NA                     NA
3:          Xkr4   6094                      0                     NA                     NA
4:       Gm18956    480                      0                     NA                     NA
5:       Gm37180   2819                      0                     NA                     NA
6:       Gm37363   2233                      1                     NA                     NA
   R210811_2460_Tg_counts R210812_2461_WT_counts R210813_2461_WT_counts R210814_2462_Tg_counts
1:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
2:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
3:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
4:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
5:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
6:                     NA                     NA                     NA                     NA
```

So my question is how to get rid of the NA values and if it is possible to merge the counts column of each csv file into a single file.

Thanks,

Sara

Comment: I would say you have to at first make it work on one file. Write a function which gives you  your required result in terms of columns etc.. For the `data.table` you can load files into one `DT` by using  `rbindlist(lapply(list.files(...), function(x) {YourDataTransformationFunction}))`. As long you you can keep the column names the same it will simply collapse everything into one table. For now the issue seems to be that you have different column names or multiple columns instead of 3 (?).
Do you have an example from one file?

Comment: Welcome to SO! One issue might be that the count columns of your CSVs have different names. Hence, you could rename them before binding into one using e.g. `map_df(~ fread(.) %>% rename(counts = 3))` or `map_df(~ fread(.) %>% mutate(id = names(.)[[3]]) |> rename(counts = 3))` which will add an id with original column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 columns on all the files you could use code which could look something like this:

```r
FileList <- list.files(path = "/Users/asdf/Desktop/cardio_metabolism_annotated_counts/asdf RNA seq/raw_data/", pattern = "*.csv")
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(FileList, function(x) {
  tmpDT <- fread(input = x)
  tmpDT[,SampleID:=colnames(tmpDT)[3],]
  setnames(x = tmpDT, old = colnames(tmpDT)[3], new = "Count")
  return(tmpDT)
}))
```

This should return you a `data.table` with corrected columns. You can change the names etc. to what is more suitable for you.

To get a more detailed solution you could post one of your files after loading it with `fread`

Edit:

We can also just look at one table which we can load in the typical `fread` way. Since I don't have your files I will just make up some data and assume you have a similar structure (maybe different names).

```r
library(data.table)

# make up data
tmpDT <- data.table(GeneID=LETTERS, Length=sample.int(26), GeneName1_Count=sample(x = 0:4, size = 26, replace = T))

tmpDT
#    GeneID Length GeneName1_Count
# 1:      A     15               3
# 2:      B     20               0
# 3:      C      5               0
# 4:      D     24               4
# 5:      E      7               4
#---                              
#22:      V     11               3
#23:      W     13               0
#24:      X     25               1
#25:      Y     10               3
#26:      Z     17               0

# add one column with the name of the sample
# so that we keep track of it as well if needed
tmpDT[,SampleID:=colnames(tmpDT)[3],]

# change the name of the count column to "Count"
setnames(x = tmpDT, old = colnames(tmpDT)[3], new = "Count")

# return the new DT
tmpDT
#    GeneID Length Count        SampleID
# 1:      A     15     3 GeneName1_Count
# 2:      B     20     0 GeneName1_Count
# 3:      C      5     0 GeneName1_Count
# 4:      D     24     4 GeneName1_Count
# 5:      E      7     4 GeneName1_Count
#---                                    
#22:      V     11     3 GeneName1_Count
#23:      W     13     0 GeneName1_Count
#24:      X     25     1 GeneName1_Count
#25:      Y     10     3 GeneName1_Count
#26:      Z     17     0 GeneName1_Count
```

So this would be the part after you read in the data with `fread`.

The `lapply` part goes over your list of files applies the function inside which loads the data, transforms it and returns a list. Then `rbindlist` collapses the list into one `data.table` with all your information.

Comment: Thank you very much dparthier and @stefan . You were right about the issue. When I open my files individually the name of the columns is always "GeneID", "Length" and "R210808_2459_Tg_counts" in that order. The last column name changes for each sample (ie. "NUMBER_Tg or WT_counts"). Sorry if I seem a bit lost, I am still not sure how to run the function you showed previously to homogenize the names of the third column.

Comment: I added some more information in the edit. I assume you have `data.table` loaded.